# React datepicker set min and max date

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-datepicker

I am using react-datepicker in my project.
I need to display only days for a specific month (lets say February 2020). I was under the impression that I could pass iso dates as minDate and maxDate but this does not seem to work.

My code:

```
   const DatePickerMod = () => {
    const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(null);
  return (
    <DatePicker
      selected={startDate}
      onChange={date => setStartDate(date)}
      minDate={'02-01-2020'}
      maxDate={'02-29-2020}
      placeholderText="Select a date in February 2020"
    />
  );
  };
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

pass your date (with that format) as string to a `new Date()` instance like so:

```js
 <DatePicker
    selected={startDate}
    onChange={date => setStartDate(date)}
    minDate={new Date("02-01-2020")}
    maxDate={new Date("02-29-2020")}
    placeholderText="Select a date in February 2020"
/>
```

Answer (score 2):

`minDate` and `maxDate` are `Date` objects not `String`.

```
<DatePicker
  selected={startDate}
  onChange={date => setStartDate(date)}
  minDate={new Date(2020, 1, 1)}
  maxDate={new Date(2020, 1, 29)}
  placeholderText="Select a date in February 2020"
/>
```

[MDN Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

[React DatePicker Documentation](https://reactdatepicker.com/#example-min-date)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to use input type date field follow this

In your render use like this.

```
<input type="date" name="DOB"  min={minDate} max={today} />
```

and declare some variable in js like this

```
var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth() + 1; //January is 0 so need to add 1 to make it 1!
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

if (dd < 10) {
    dd = '0' + dd
}

if (mm < 10) {
    mm = '0' + mm
}

today = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;
var minDate = "1993-05-25"
```

This will help you to avoid any external installations

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the SingleDatePicker component instead of the DateRangePicker component, you will need to use isOutsideRange prop as minDate and maxDate don't exist on SingleDatePicker.

```
<SingleDatePicker
  standardProps...
  isOutsideRange={(day) => {
    if (minDate) return minDate > day ? true : false;
    if (maxDate) return maxDate < day ? true : false;
    return false;
  }}
/>
```