# Inquiry Regarding Time Restrictions in react-multi-date-picker

Tags: javascript

I'm currently working with react-multi-date-picker and I'm facing a challenge regarding time restrictions, specifically with the TimePicker component. I've explored the documentation and found that there are no apparent props like minTime and maxTime available.

My goal is to restrict the selection of time within a specific range (e.g., from 8:00 AM to 6:00 PM), and after 6:00 PM, it should roll over to 8:00 AM of the next day.

Could anyone provide guidance on how to implement time restrictions or if there are any workarounds within the react-multi-date-picker library? Your insights and assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: You can get answer from here:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60251624/react-datepicker-set-min-and-max-date